Create docker container for .sbt Scala
I want to create a Docker container for a simple "Hello World" code that I wrote in Scala.
I am gettin an

"ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c sbt clean compile package" did not complete successfully: exit code: 134".

I read that code 134 can refer to low memory so I cranked up the available memory to max for docker. The error still persists.
Now, I wonder how can one deal with this issue. Is there any other way (possibly more optimized) to configure the Dockerfile to create a docker container for .sbt Scala?
My directory structure is

FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:8u222_1.3.5_2.13.1 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY build.sbt .
COPY project /app/project
# Download dependencies first (reduces build failures)

COPY src /app/src

# Compile and package the Scala application
RUN sbt clean compile package

FROM openjdk:24-slim-bullseye
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]


Are you sure you want to compile your code inside a Docker? Also, it seems you are mixing two different JDKs for compiling and running, while that is fine is usually better to try to align them.

Can you share the complete output of docker build? Did you try to run other commands like RUN sbt --version just for troubleshooting? Also, I'd probably recommend to use more recent version of SBT and Java for the build phase.

Have a look to https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html It will simplify your process a lot. BTW, that error is in the compilation stage build. You should have more logs. Also, don't use the outdated hseeberger/scala-sbt. There is an official sbt docker image at https://github.com/sbt/docker-sbt
